# Anyone else having this 'disappearing' BitcoinCash issue with BitcoinABC wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, ecash

Today I was in claim BitcoinCash mode, which I completed successfully with my Ledger Nano S and also with my Trezor. Then it was time to for the Bitcoins I held only in my Electrum wallet. I retrieved the private keys and set out to import one into a new BitcoinCash wallet. All bitcoins were first moved off Electrum to a different wallet on a different computer. I then installed the BitcoinABC.org wallet. When that was done I encrypted it immediately. I then used importprivkey to import a private Bitcoin key that had previously held .1 bitcoin.

The blockchain scan started. I let it run and went to lunch. When I got back, the .1 bitcoin cash had been received, but there was also a send transaction 39 minutes later to a BCC address (36uzTBVeWN2pvUu3YX22gCutovGwQg1eeS) I don't know. I didn't make the send transaction and there are no other people that could have and no computer issues, malware or otherwise on my end. Also, I had a list of other private keys open on the same computer and only issue is with the one key I imported to BitcoinABC wallet.

How was BCC sent from my encrypted wallet, where only I <s>(and BitcoinABC wallet after importing)</s> have the private key, <s>if there isn't a vulnerability in the BitcoinABC wallet?</s>

Has anyone else had this issue with BitcoinABC wallet?

Is there a BitcoinABC wallet rep on this site that can address this issue?

[image]

Comment: That send is from before the fork on 3/31/2017. That means that you sent Bitcoin on 3/31/2017 to 36uzTBVeWN2pvUu3YX22gCutovGwQg1eeS, and because Bitcoin Cash shares the same history as Bitcoin, you will see this send in your wallet.

Comment: @AndrewChow Sounds like that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @AndrewChow Yes, thanks, that makes total sense now. I should have realized that, as the next transaction in my Electrum is that same send address. Plus, the dates and times of the transactions are the same as previous BTC transactions. Light bulb on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That send is from before the fork on 3/31/2017. That means that you sent Bitcoin on 3/31/2017 to 36uzTBVeWN2pvUu3YX22gCutovGwQg1eeS, and because Bitcoin Cash shares the same history as Bitcoin, you will see this send in your wallet.